# Change/derivative of curvature in discrete time

Tags: reference-frames, curvature, differentiation, centripetal-force

I would like to calculate the change or derivative of curvature $\kappa$ of a moving object in discrete time. The curvature can be calculated according to:

$$
\kappa = \frac{1}{R} = \frac{\dot{\theta}}{v_x} = \frac{a_y}{v_x^2}
$$

where $\dot{\theta}$ is the yaw rate (yaw speed), $a_y$ the lateral acceleration and $v_x$ the longitudinal velocity.

Now to calculate the curvature $\kappa_t$ at the current time $t$ the curvature $\kappa_{t-1}$ at the previous time $t-1$ and the change in curvature $\Delta \kappa$ is needed.

$$
\kappa_{t} = \kappa_{t-1} + \Delta t \frac{d}{dt} \left(\frac{\dot{\theta}}{v_x}\right) \\
= \kappa_{t-1} + \Delta t \frac{d}{dt} \left(\frac{a_y}{v_x^2}\right)
$$

My problem is that I don't know how to calculated the change in curvature given the absolut velocity $v$, absolut acceleration $a$, yaw angle $\theta$ and yaw rate $\dot{\theta}$ at discrete time steps.

---

I am not sure if it is correct to set $v_x = v\cos(\theta)$ and $a_y = a \sin(\theta)$ because of frame of reference. How can I get the derivatives in discrete time?

$$
\frac{d}{dt} \left(\frac{\dot{\theta}}{v_x}\right) = \frac{\ddot{\theta} v_x - \dot{v_x} \dot{\theta}}{v_x^2} = \ldots ? \\
\frac{d}{dt} \left(\frac{a_y}{v_x^2}\right) = \frac{\dot{a_y}v_x^2- a_y2v_x a_x}{v_x^4} = \ldots ?
$$